# How to install sth in kubernetes container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, kubernetes

I want to install mysql-connector==2.1.6 in python container. One way is writing this command in DockerFile

```
RUN pip install mysql-connector==2.1.6
```

And make images and use that image in kubernetes. But I want to run python images and after that install mysql-connector==2.1.6 But after crashing container or rebooting it ,I should install mysql-connector==2.1.6 again.
After a lot of search I see [cloud_provider](https://docs.jelastic.com/connection-to-mysql-python) that install packages in running container. But it does not explain how it do that. Now I have kubernetes and I want to permanently install some packages on running container.
 What should I do?

**I know I can commit container but I do not want it  because I do not know when the user install packages.**

Comment: You should edit your `Dockerfile` the way you describe (or, better, add it to your application’s pip `requirements.txt` file).  Pods get deleted frequently and you shouldn’t try to install software there.

Comment: The cloud provider do it. I think it should have someway. If i add it to  requirements.txt I should build docker images again

Comment: Yes, you do need to rebuild your Docker images when you make a change like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard and fast rule that changes to the container are ephemeral.  If the container shuts down, they're gone.  You could maybe try to put all configuration files into permanent storage, but that would be a nightmare.  Long story short, if you want it to last, you need to make it part of the image.

Comment: but how can cloud provider handle it?
They gave their users some container and when you install sth and reboot it they are just there and we do not need install them again

Comment: One way or the other they are updating the container.  You could make it part of the startup CMD when the container is run, but I don't see a good way of doing it dynamically.

Comment: If i add it to CMD i should build my image againt.

Comment: Yup, I agree. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider `initContainers`?

Init Containers always run before App Container in a Pod. In addition all initContainers **must complete succesfully** (there can be a series of `initContainers)`.
According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#pod-v1-core) :

> List of initialization containers belonging to the pod. Init
>   containers are executed in order prior to containers being started. If
>   any init container fails, the pod is considered to have failed and is
>   handled according to its restartPolicy.

Via `initContainers` you can include some security content which should not be in image, it can contain utilities or scripts (like install of mysql-connector).

More information about `initContainers` and examples [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#understanding-init-containers).

Comment: No I do not mean this. I want to keep the installtion of my user automatically

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use Kubernetes pods as a replacement for traditional "virtual machines" or "VPSs", where a user "logs in" to the pods and manually runs commands to install their application.

*Kubernetes is not designed to be used that way*. It is designed to treat pods as disposable. It automatically restarts pods in many different scenarios (node going down, node running out of resources, etc). When a pod gets restarted, all the "manual changes" are lost. This is *by design*, you should not try to fight that.

You need to build the *complete, final* container image including Python, the libraries and the application code in your Dockerfile, then build it and push it to a registry, and then run it in Kubernetes. You should never need to manually log in to a container.

Something like this should work

```
FROM python:3.7

# Install any dependencies you need
RUN pip install mysql-connector==2.1.6

# Copy all the application source to the container.
COPY src/ /app

# Set the entrypoint to your main python file.
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main.py"]
```

Comment: No I do not want to write dockerfile as you said I want to treat container as vps.one thing that I can do is mount the / to volume but kubernetes can not do that

Comment: I do not know which package user want to install and I want to do it in running container without commit

Comment: Some cloud provider do that.

Comment: Kubernetes is not designed as a VPS substitute. It's the wrong tool for your job. If you want to provide VPS-like experience to your users, you will have to use something like Xen, OpenVZ, LXC.